# How to get Rest Api endpoints, name and url's, in the way Azure Functions do?

Tags: asp.net-web-api

Sometimes you get over a feature that you just like. When creating a Azure Function project and debugs it, it writes out this nice info in the console.

Now that I am writing the frontend, I have found this information very useful.

```
Functions:

        CoWorkers: [GET,POST] http://localhost:7071/api/CoWorkers

        GetManager: [GET,POST] http://localhost:7071/api/GetManager

        SetManager: [GET,POST] http://localhost:7071/api/SetManager

        UserInfo: [GET,POST] http://localhost:7071/api/UserInfo
...
```

I would like to have this on every asp.net rest api project that I am coding.
Anyone knows how to get it?

EDIT: OpenApi/Swagger is providing this information as pawelek91 says and I should have mentioned that I want it in the console: "Just because I like that feature".

Answer (score 0):

use HttpOption request or swagger (if you can install it on your backend)

Comment: Swagger (OpenApi) is a natural part of a rest api project for me. I just thought if it was an "easy way out", I would use it. Could you elaborate on the "HttpOption request" part?

Comment: just send option query (instead post, get) to endpoint and you will get response like "handled methods : get,put"
it is always sended before we exaclly send get/post/put/delete request to check if this request can be handled

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods/OPTIONS

Answer (score 0):

For console access to your web API, try the new HttpRepl tool at:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/web-api/http-repl/

It's a dotnet CLI tool that is installed separately (install using `dotnet tool install -g Microsoft.dotnet-httprepl` from the CL).  Then you can "browse" your API using this command line tool.

As noted in the docs, it requires .Net Core 2.1+.

Comment: Nice! Today I am using vs.code extention Rest Client, but I can clearly see that this can be useful. (tried to post a link...)